# Java thread InterruptedException block not executing

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupted-exception

My Java class is given below. It's a small exercise to test thread join (wait) and thread sleep (timed wait).

```
public class BasicThreadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testThreadWait();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " exiting");
    }

    private static void testThreadWait() {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
            String currentThread = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println(String.format("%s execution started", currentThread));
            long waitMillis = 20000L;
            try {
                System.out.println(String.format("%s going for timed wait of %d millis", currentThread, waitMillis));
                Thread.sleep(waitMillis);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(String.format("%s timed wait over after %d millis", currentThread, waitMillis));
            }
            System.out.println(String.format("%s execution ending", currentThread));
        });
        thread1.setName("Thread-1");

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
            String currentThread = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println(String.format("%s execution started", currentThread));
            try {
                System.out.println(currentThread + " about to wait for " + thread1.getName());
                thread1.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(String.format("%s wait over for %s", currentThread, thread1.getName()));
            }
            System.out.println(String.format("%s execution ending", currentThread));
        });
        thread2.setName("Thread-2");

        thread2.start();
        thread1.start();
    }
}
```

No matter what order I start the two threads in I never get the two `InterruptedException` blocks executed in either `sleep()` or `join()`. Below is a sample output:

```
Thread-2 execution started
Thread-2 about to wait for Thread-1
main exiting
Thread-1 execution started
Thread-1 going for timed wait of 20000 millis
Thread-1 execution ending
Thread-2 execution ending
```

Any explanation on why this is happening?

Comment: Where do you interrupt the threads? You won't get an `InterruptedException` if you don't actually interrupt them.

Comment: Makes sense, I had assumed that `InterruptedException` would always be thrown once wait or timed wait is over. That is not the case and looks like there has to be an explicit invocation of `interrupt()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get an `InterruptedException` if you don't actually interrupt the threads.

You could try, for example:

```
    thread2.start();
    thread1.start();
    
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    thread1.interrupt();
    thread2.interrupt();
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/4h7sJ9)

Output:

```
Thread-2 execution started
Thread-1 execution started
Thread-1 going for timed wait of 20000 millis
Thread-2 about to wait for Thread-1
Thread-1 timed wait over after 20000 millis
Thread-1 execution ending
Thread-2 wait over for Thread-1
Thread-2 execution ending
main exiting
```

Answer (score 1):

`wait()` does not throw an `InterruptedException` when the block (or wait) finishes.

If you start a third thread that calls `thread1.interrupt()` then you will get the `InterruptedException`.